# Fastlane build failed

Tags: flutter, fastlane

Im configuring the fastlane build for the first time.I don't have idea about this issue.Please help

[![Could not open settings generic class cache for settings file '/Volumes/Files/22/17/learn/uber_app/driver app new/driver_app_new/android/settings.gradle' (/Users/admin/.gradle/caches/6.6/scripts/dvrvymk2d1pk34aa6juknj4vr).

> BUG! exception in phase 'semantic analysis' in source unit '*BuildScript*' Unsupported class file major version 60][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pcQlc.png)][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pcQlc.png)

Answer (score 0):

I changed my Java 16 version to
java version "15.0.2" 2021-01-19
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 15.0.2+7-27)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 15.0.2+7-27, mixed mode, sharing)

Issue resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Gradle prior to 7.0 is not compatible with Java 16: [GitHub: Gradle issue #13481](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/13481).
Either use Gradle 7 or run Gradle using an older JDK: [Using Java 16 with Gradle](https://melix.github.io/blog/2021/03/gradle-java16.html).